# Android Change Toolbar/Widget Background to Black in ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar

Tags: java, styles, android-widget, themes, customization

[image: Action Bar Menu Must Stay Grey]
[image: Popup Menu Must Stay Grey]
[image: Widget with same background as app, need widget to be black]

Hi I just designed a custom widget with a popup menu. This means by default I have to extend AppCompatActivity and am forced to use 
Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar or
ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark or 
ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar

The thing is, I would like to have the widget that I used to replace the action bar black and keep the popup menu grey and the menu that comes up by pressing the device action menu grey. Could anyone please post sample code to accompany a description of how to do this. At this stage telling me how to will not help because I have tried using java and changing primary and dark colors in the theme. I also tried adding multiple custom styling in styles.xml which I ended up commenting out and eventually deleting. Please see my code below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:titleTextColor="#fff"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:title="@string/app_name"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
   />
```

```
package com.example.android.widget;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewParent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        myToolbar.setTitle("Widget");
        myToolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        myToolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));
        View titleView = getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        if (titleView != null) {
            ViewParent parent = titleView.getParent();
            if (parent != null && (parent instanceof View)) {
                View parentView = (View)parent;
                parentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));
            }
        }
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Menu options to set and cancel the alarm.
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // When the user clicks START ALARM, set the alarm.
            case R.id.start_action:

                return true;
            // When the user clicks CANCEL ALARM, cancel the alarm.
            case R.id.cancel_action:

                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}


<resources><!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorBackground</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

```
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/start_action"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/start_text"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    />
<item android:id="@+id/cancel_action"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/cancel_text"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know you dont need to extend the AppCompactActivity because you are using a custom Toolbar.
I came accross the same issue last months and the way i solved it was to get rid of the AppCompactActivity extention and put this instead:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

and to see how the app would look while styling and coding it you need to choose the preview to AppNoTitleBarFullScreen.

also on your `OnCreate()` method you need to add the following:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.Your_Activity);
        ...
}
```

And on your styles XML file add the following:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar.FullScreen">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item> 
</style>
```

I belive thats it!... please anybody correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @JqueryNinja as i said on my answer, i came accross the same issue a week ago or so and it solved my issue so maybe perhaps you have a bug somewhere else. maybe somebody else will be willing to help you from now on. good luck and al the best!

Comment: Your answer sheds light but a lot still had to be done. Thanks!